# Calculate percentages in skimr::skim_with

Tags: r, skimr

I am trying to add percentages of levels of factor to `skimr::skim` output. I tried to use the `table` function but it did not work as intended. I can I get the percentages of the different species in the correct format, similar to `top_count`?

```r
library(skimr)
skim(iris)
```

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Name | iris |
| Number of rows | 150 |
| Number of columns | 5 |
| _______________________ |  |
| Column type frequency: |  |
| factor | 1 |
| numeric | 4 |
| ________________________ |  |
| Group variables | None |

Data summary

**Variable type: factor**

| skim_variable | n_missing | complete_rate | ordered | n_unique | top_counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Species | 0 | 1 | FALSE | 3 | set: 50, ver: 50, vir: 50 |

**Variable type: numeric**

| skim_variable | n_missing | complete_rate | mean | sd | p0 | p25 | p50 | p75 | p100 | hist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sepal.Length | 0 | 1 | 5.84 | 0.83 | 4.3 | 5.1 | 5.80 | 6.4 | 7.9 | ▆▇▇▅▂ |
| Sepal.Width | 0 | 1 | 3.06 | 0.44 | 2.0 | 2.8 | 3.00 | 3.3 | 4.4 | ▁▆▇▂▁ |
| Petal.Length | 0 | 1 | 3.76 | 1.77 | 1.0 | 1.6 | 4.35 | 5.1 | 6.9 | ▇▁▆▇▂ |
| Petal.Width | 0 | 1 | 1.20 | 0.76 | 0.1 | 0.3 | 1.30 | 1.8 | 2.5 | ▇▁▇▅▃ |

```r
my_skim <- skim_with(factor=sfl(pct = ~prop.table(table(.))))
my_skim(iris)
```

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Name | iris |
| Number of rows | 150 |
| Number of columns | 5 |
| _______________________ |  |
| Column type frequency: |  |
| factor | 1 |
| numeric | 4 |
| ________________________ |  |
| Group variables | None |

Data summary

**Variable type: factor**

| skim_variable | n_missing | complete_rate | ordered | n_unique | top_counts | pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Species | 0 | 1 | FALSE | 3 | set: 50, ver: 50, vir: 50 | 0.3333333 |
| Species | 0 | 1 | FALSE | 3 | set: 50, ver: 50, vir: 50 | 0.3333333 |
| Species | 0 | 1 | FALSE | 3 | set: 50, ver: 50, vir: 50 | 0.3333333 |

**Variable type: numeric**

| skim_variable | n_missing | complete_rate | mean | sd | p0 | p25 | p50 | p75 | p100 | hist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sepal.Length | 0 | 1 | 5.84 | 0.83 | 4.3 | 5.1 | 5.80 | 6.4 | 7.9 | ▆▇▇▅▂ |
| Sepal.Width | 0 | 1 | 3.06 | 0.44 | 2.0 | 2.8 | 3.00 | 3.3 | 4.4 | ▁▆▇▂▁ |
| Petal.Length | 0 | 1 | 3.76 | 1.77 | 1.0 | 1.6 | 4.35 | 5.1 | 6.9 | ▇▁▆▇▂ |
| Petal.Width | 0 | 1 | 1.20 | 0.76 | 0.1 | 0.3 | 1.30 | 1.8 | 2.5 | ▇▁▇▅▃ |

<sup>Created on 2022-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `paste` (`str_c`) to create a single string

```
library(skimr)
my_skim <- skim_with(factor=sfl(pct = ~{
     prt <- prop.table(table(.))
     val <- sprintf("%.2f", prt)
     nm1 <- tolower(substr(names(prt), 1, 3))
      stringr::str_c(nm1, val, sep = ": ", collapse = ", ")
      })
)
```

-testing

```
> my_skim(iris)
── Data Summary ────────────────────────
                           Values
Name                       iris  
Number of rows             150   
Number of columns          5     
_______________________          
Column type frequency:           
  factor                   1     
  numeric                  4     
________________________         
Group variables            None  

── Variable type: factor ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  skim_variable n_missing complete_rate ordered n_unique top_counts                pct                            
1 Species               0             1 FALSE          3 set: 50, ver: 50, vir: 50 set: 0.33, ver: 0.33, vir: 0.33

── Variable type: numeric ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  skim_variable n_missing complete_rate  mean    sd    p0   p25   p50   p75  p100 hist 
1 Sepal.Length          0             1  5.84 0.828   4.3   5.1  5.8    6.4   7.9 ▆▇▇▅▂
2 Sepal.Width           0             1  3.06 0.436   2     2.8  3      3.3   4.4 ▁▆▇▂▁
3 Petal.Length          0             1  3.76 1.77    1     1.6  4.35   5.1   6.9 ▇▁▆▇▂
4 Petal.Width           0             1  1.20 0.762   0.1   0.3  1.3    1.8   2.5 ▇▁▇▅▃
```